# header location does not work in facebook app

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to redirect users to the permission page in my facebook app if they have not added the app. The problem is that using the following just sends them to a page with a large blue facebook logo that the user has to click to see the permissions.

```
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'req_perms' => 'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_photos,user_videos',

));

header("Location: ".$login_url);
```

I am using an iframe app. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to get redirects working properly within your Facebook Canvas app is through client-side redirect:

```
<script>
    top.location.href="<?php echo $login_url; ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it but when the user accepts the permissions they are sent back to a page outside of the facebook layout. My example page would be http://www.mysite.com/view.php?. The get sent to that page instead of the app (http://apps.facebook.com/myapp

Comment: Can you confirm that the forwarding address is a child of your URLs in the FB app settings here?  http://drktd.com/45a8

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. The site is set as http://www.mysite.com/ and the domain is set as mysite.com. Canvas url is set to http://www.mysite.com/view.php?

Comment: I'm not sure what `getLoginUrl` does, but I know you can construct it manually to point to whatever post-auth URL you like.  I also found this highly relevant post on StackO:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173318/facebook-oauth-login-for-iframe-canvas-apps-displays-a-logo-image-and-a-go-to-fac

Answer (score 3):

try it between "ob_start();" and "ob_end_flush();"

eg:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
        header(Location : http://site.com/path/url.php ");
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Iframe applications are supposed to run inside a canvas iframe, but should also be able to run as standalone sites.  Here's the javascript/php code we use to first detect if we are in an iframe and then pass the proper 'next' value so the user comes back to the right page:

```
if (top.location != location) { // in iframe
    top.location.href = "<?=$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('next' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/'))?>";
} else {
    location.href = "<?=$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('next' => 'http://www.myapp.com/'))?>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FBML then try this

```
<fb:redirect url="http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/?not_in_group" />
```

[Check Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/redirect/)

Answer (score 0):

jason I experienced the same thing, both in Flex and Javascript. A big blue Facebook logo with nothing else.

The page that you need to open an iframe in must be a facebook page. Otherwise you will always get that blue thing. Facebook is doing something that prevents opening an iframe to facebook. If anyone can tell us what it is, it will be great.

In that case, i switched to browser extensions. Browser extensions can use cross site scripting. Do not waste your time with trying to find another way. I wasted 3 days reading every bit of info i found, to no avail.