# How do you redirect a user to the Facebook login page from within the canvas?

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Login and Iframe redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457620/facebook-login-and-iframe-redirection)

When a user is not logged onto facebook but visits the canvas URL directly, the app shows up in the logged off state because no access token (or signed request) is being sent to it.

BUT since the application is framed and I'm NOT using the Javascript SDK (using Perl OAuth Module), how do I tell Facebook to jump to the login page instead of loading the logged-off canvas app page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this same issue while attempting to redirect users to PayPal to make a payment.

The problem you're trying to explain is this:

- Facebook canvas apps are not allowed to access the parent window
- Canvas apps may only redirect to domains included in the **App Domain** field of the app's **Basic Info** section in the settings (`https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<app_id>/summary`)

The only way to accomplish authentication is to:

- Use the JavaScript SDK to pop up an auth window, or
- Use JavaScript to redirect to the Facebook oauth page (`top.location = "<url>"`)

Answer (score 1):

Since you own the code to the iframe, you should do the redirection with your code.  Facebook only loads the URL you have set in the app settings.  For app settings, there isn't a url for logged in and a url for logged out.

Comment: but i cant redirect on the server side from within the iframe, are you suggesting I use Javascript?

Comment: Why can't you redirect with your server-side code?  Isn't your code in control over what your send to the client?

Comment: yes, but isnt the end result still Javascript? When I say I cant do this on the server side I mean through header redirects -- because the app is contained in an iframe. Do you get what I mean brother?

Comment: When the user lands on your page, you're decoding the `signed_request` your server receives in the HTTP Post parameters to find out if they're logged in or not, correct?

Comment: Sure you can.  I do this with production code.  C# code is: `Response.Write("<script>top.location.href='URL HERE';</script>");Response.End();`